# How can I assign a linq result to this object?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I want to write a model which will look like this:

```
public class Profile : Models.Users {

    ModdDBEntities db = new ModdDBEntities();

    public Profile( int user_id ) {
        this = (Profile)( 
                    from u in db.Users.Where(r => r.user_id == user_id ) 
                    select u 
        ).First();
    }
}
```

Is there any method to assign a values of every properties to this?

Comment: If you manage to do this, you'll break LinqToSql object tracking (two instances now exist with the same identification).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to copy all properties from one object to another, you can do this:

```
foreach (var obj1Property in obj1.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    var obj2Property = obj2.GetType().GetProperty(obj1Property.Name);
    obj2Property.SetValue(obj2, obj1Property.GetValue(obj1, null), null);
}
```

Where in your case, `obj1` is the profile object, and `obj2` is `this`.

This only copies public properties, and of course, doesn't check to ensure that obj2's type declares all of the properties found in obj1's type. Nor does it check that the same-named properties in both types are of the same type themselves. But it should get you started.

Not that I'd recommend doing this except in very unusual cases.

Comment: Yep, there are couple Object 2 Object mappers at the market (like Automapper or BLToolkit). But even in this case it's much preferable to use as simplest solution as possible, and manual or automatic property mapping seems not so simple.

Comment: Yor solution works for non entity objects, but if I try to use in case which I showed then I got exception: InvalidOperationException: The EntityCollection has already been initialized. The InitializeRelatedCollection method should only be called to initialize a new EntityCollection during deserialization of an object graph.]
   System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.InitializeRelatedCollection(String relationshipName, String targetRoleName, EntityCollection`1 entityCollection)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a factory method:

```
public static Profile ReadProfile()
{
   var query = from u in db.Users.Where(r => r.user_id == user_id ) 
               select u;
   return query.First();
}
```

This is much more preferable way from different prospectives. First of all this isn't an ordinary construction. Users of your Profile class could not expect any database related operations during ordinary default constructors call and using factory method is more clear way of representing your intention. Second, its simplifies further changes. For example, even more preferable way of implementing data access layer (a.k.a. DAL) is creating brand new class (or set of classes) that whould incapsulate all database related operations.

For example, you could create separate interface:

```
interface IProfileRepository
{
  Profile ReadProfile();
}
```

And then create your concrete repository:

```
class ProfileRepository : IProfileRepository
{
  public Profile ReadProfile() { .. implementation skipped .. }
}
```

In this case you separating your logic even more. And this allows you simply "substitute" your real classes (like ProfileRepository) with "fake" classes that returns "fake" objects.

This technique called "[mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)" and it's especially useful for creating unit tests that did not use any external resources like databases.

Comment: Yeah, I know but this isnt what I need. I want to do everything in constructor.

Comment: No, you can't do this. All you can do - is to assign all fields or properties. But any way, I'm strongly recommended not doing this. Creating separate method (or even separate class) is much preferable approach. What are you trying to achieve that you need this?

Comment: Your example wont work because db isnt static and I cant cast from Users to Profile because Profile inherit from User and not inversely. My example was to show purpoose only any isnt correct.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot set anything to this(self). You can only set the properties of fields from within the object but not the instance.

Make your method static and return the profile object from the method

```
public static Profile GetProfile( int user_id ) {
       var prof = (Profile)( 
                    from u in db.Users.Where(r => r.user_id == user_id ) 
                    select u 
        ).First();
return prof
    }
```

or write method to copy all properties. You can use reflection to copy properties of profile to this, without mentioning fields name.

Comment: And there arent any methods to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you have to write your own. I created one method once which copy all properties from object1 to object2 using reflection, I need to find it.